# UIPasteboard setItems: options API, UTType.plainText: swift usage

Tags: ios, swift, uipasteboard, uttype

I'm trying to use the following API in Swift: [UIPasteboard: setItems(_:options:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipasteboard/1829417-setitems)
, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60121588/trying-to-retrieve-pasteboard-value-after-10-s-with-background-task):

```
UIPasteboard.general.setItems([[kUTTypeUTF8PlainText as String: text]], options: [.expirationDate : Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 10)])
```

However, it seems that the `kUTTypeUTF8PlainText` constant has been deprecated and I need to use the [UniformTypeIdentifiers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers) framework:

```
pasteboard.setItems([[String(UTType.plainText): string]],
                    options: [.expirationDate: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 120)])
```

However, the `setItems:` method accept only `String` type as the key, so I need to somehow convert the `UTType.plainText` to be of type `String`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`identifier`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttype/3551507-identifier) property (also note the equivalent type is called `utf8PlainText`):

```
UTType.utf8PlainText.identifier
```

As the documentation says:

> API that doesn’t use UTType uses a `String` or `CFString` to refer to a type by its identifier.

And `UIPasteBoard` is such an API.

Comment: 'identifier' is only available in iOS 14.0 or newer

Comment: @karlingen I'm pretty sure the entire `UniformTypeIdentifiers` API is introduced in iOS 14, so this entire Q&A is probably not for you if you are supporting earlier versions. Do note however, that [over 90% of people are using iOS 14+.](https://iosref.com/ios-usage) Maybe also consider whether it is worth the effort to support whatever version that you are supporting.